# HTK | Convert HMM Definitions from Binary to Text

Tags: binary, ascii, htk

I have the HMM definition file for a trained model, but it is in binary. How do I convert it into text/ASCII for easier usage? I obtained this trained model from http://www.keithv.com/software/htk/us/

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem and found somewhere that HHEd is the solution:

HHEd -H binary_hmmdefs -w ascii_hmmdefs null.hed tiedlist

where tiedlist is a file containing all phonemes used by hmm definition file,
and null.hed is a blank file you have to create as a dummy for HHEd to do the job.